# jQuery not posting JSON

Tags: jquery, couchdb

I am trying to use the CouchDB API to [query a specific view](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.3.1/api/ddoc/views.html#post--db-_design-ddoc-_view-view). Here is what I am using:

```
  $.post(targetURL,
    {
      "keys": ["Query Value"]
    },
    function (data, status) {
      console.log("Data");
      console.log(data);
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

However, when running this I get this 415 code:

"bad_content_type", reason: "Content-Type must be application/json"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look at JSON.stringify, then just make a js object and post like this: JSON.stringify({keys: ["Query Value"]})

Comment: You could also just use $.ajax and then set the content type: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @MartinM I did try using JSON.stringify and got the same error

Comment: @MartinM Can you post an answer that details how this would be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try something like:

```
var dataModel = {
  keys: ["Query Value"]
};
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://xxxxxxxxx',
  type: 'POST',
  content: 'application/json',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: JSON.stringify(dataModel),
  success: function(data, status, xhr){

  }
});
```